# Cusrom QR UI Flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

I want to have QR scan capability in flutter app along with other camera functionalities. I can't find any package that provides this functionality with the option to use your own camera controller. Instead there are QR scanning packages which implement their own controllers with their UIs. I don't want to use multiple camera controllers (one my own and another of the package). I only want to provide a specific area of the screen ( like a box ), with the cameraPreview() of my camera controller underneath it, where the package can 'SEE' and then return the QR code value.
Can anyone help? If I knew how to make a flutter plugin I would but sadly I don't have any android or IOS programming knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner should work for you.

I created a similar screen with a square inside a modalBottomsheet to scan QR Codes.

For this i wrapped the QRView inside a Container with the device height * 0.5 (50%)

```
 Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
        child: QRView(
          overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
            borderColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          key: qrKey,
          onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
        ),
      ),
```

You can set the width and height as you wish inside the Container.

The controller of this package lets you:

- Flip the camera
- turn on/off flash
- resume/pause the camera